# GUI Python drag and drop

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

can anyone help me with my problem? I want to make a simple drag-and-drop GUI that contains 3 icons on the left side and a graphical view on the right side which is where we can drop our icons,  It was working fine until I made some changes, i wanted to add 3 things:

1. When left-clicking on the items on the graphic view ,an empty widget opens.
2. When right-clicking on them a text menu shows that contains a  bunch of items like:save ,edit ,delete...
3. I want to be able to see the coordinates of the items printed in the code terminal as we move them in the graphic view

**The problem is the clicking methods are applied on the fixed icons on the left side, not the ones we drop and want to work on the graphic view**

[Here is how it looks when running:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWpNH.png)

[here is the right clicking event:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0G4G.png)

[and here is the left clicking event:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8c7V.png)

here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QMainWindow, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QToolButton, QMenu, QAction, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QDrag, QCursor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QMimeData

class DraggableIcon(QToolButton):
    def __init__(self, icon_path, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setIcon(QIcon(icon_path))
        self.setIconSize(QSize(64, 64))
        self.setFixedSize(64, 64)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True) 
        self.icon_path = icon_path

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # Left-click: Open an empty widget
            self.openEmptyWidget()
        elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            # Right-click: Show context menu
            self.showContextMenu(event)

    def openEmptyWidget(self):
        empty_widget = QDialog()
        empty_widget.setWindowTitle("Empty Widget")
        empty_widget.exec_()

    def showContextMenu(self, event):
        menu = QMenu()
        save_action = QAction("Save")
        edit_action = QAction("Edit")
        delete_action = QAction("Delete")
        
        menu.addAction(save_action)
        menu.addAction(edit_action)
        menu.addAction(delete_action)
        
        action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))

class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, scene):
        super().__init__(scene)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        mime_data = event.mimeData()
        if mime_data.hasText():
            icon_path = mime_data.text()
            pixmap = QPixmap(icon_path)
            icon_item = self.scene().addPixmap(pixmap)
            
            # Get the scene position where the drop occurred
            scene_pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            icon_item.setPos(scene_pos)
            
            # Make the item movable
            icon_item.setFlag(QGraphicsPixmapItem.ItemIsMovable)
            
            # Change cursor shape to a hand
            icon_item.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

            event.acceptProposedAction()

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Drag and drop")

        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        main_layout = QHBoxLayout(central_widget)

        icon_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Here we create Draggable Icon instances
        self.icons = ["athena_icon.png", "poseidon_icon.png", "ares_icon.png"]
        for icon_path in self.icons:
            icon_button = DraggableIcon(icon_path)
            icon_button.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))  # Set cursor for the icons
            icon_layout.addWidget(icon_button)

        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        graphics_view = MyGraphicsView(scene)
        scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 800, 800)  # Set the scene rect
        scene.setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)  # Optimize for static scenes
        
        main_layout.addLayout(icon_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(graphics_view)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.resize(800, 800)  # We set the initial size
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

thanks.

Comment: Create a subclass of QGraphicsPixmapItem and implement mouse interaction there. Then, instead of using `addPixmap()`, create an instance of the subclass and use `addItem()` with it.